# String array data needs to be stripped of dollar sign and turned into a float

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have data such as:

```
['$15.50']
['$10.00']
['$15.50']
['$15.50']
['$22.28']
['$50']
['$15.50']
['$10.00']
```

I want to get rid of the dollar sign and turn the strings into floats so I can use the numbers for several calculations. I have tried the following:

```
array[0] = float(array.text.strip('$'))
```

which gives me an attribute error, because apparently a 'list' object has no 'text' attribute. My bad. Is there a similar way for 'list' objects to get stripped? Any other suggestions would be welcome too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have bumped across another problem. My list is longer than the example I provided and some numbers have commas in them which makes the float() command bump. Meaning I have to strip it off the commas too but that seems to not work the same as with the method I used for the dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [list comprehension](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
array = [float(x.strip("$")) for x in array]
```

Answer (score 0):

With regex:

```
import re
array = ([float(re.sub("\$","",x)) for x in array])
```

In case '$' is not at the end or beginning of the string

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
[float(s.replace(',', '.').replace('$', '')) for s in array]
```

I have taken the liberty to change your data in order to consider a wider variety of test cases:

```
array = ['$15.50',
         '$ 10.00',
         '  $15.50  ',
         '$15,50',
         '$22,28 ',
         '  10,00  $  ']
```

And this is what you get:

```
In [8]: [float(s.replace(',', '.').replace('$', '')) for s in array]
Out[8]: [15.5, 10.0, 15.5, 15.5, 22.28, 10.0]
```